# How do I create the help system for Vim?

Tags: help-system

I built Vim from source and unfortunately when doing this the help system is not created (in other words you get an error if you execute :h). What is the procedure for creating the help system?

This is what I tried:

```
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
    /usr/share/vim
sudo mkdir /usr/share/vim/doc
sudo chmod 666 /usr/share/vim/doc
:helptags $VIMRUNTIME/doc
    E151: No match: /usr/share/vim/doc/**
```

The last shown error above is where I am stuck.

Comment: Well, the directory is empty, hence the error. The tags for the Vim help files are created during `make install`. In fact the tags file is created in the source directory, before the help files (incl. the tags file) are copied to the install directory. AFAIK the directory for the help files is `/usr/share/vim/vim81/doc`.

Comment: so how do you install vim from your source? Also, please note, that $VIMRUNTIME should end with e.g. vim81 for vim version 8.1